# Trouble using insertSheet function on google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been using the below code to populate a workbook with one sheet for each day of the month (1-31) automatically for years. This month the dates are showing up with a single trailing decimal (1.0, 2.0 etc).

```
for(var i = 0; i < text; i++)
{
  ss.insertSheet(i + 1, i, {template: templateSheet});
}
```

I tried using math.floor, but I still, much to my bemusement, get the decimal place afterward.

```
for(var i = 0; i < text; i++)
{
  ss.insertSheet(Math.floor(i + 1), i, {template: templateSheet});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a number to a string by using .toFixed(), your code can be like below

```
for(var i = 0; i < text; i++)
{
  ss.insertSheet((i + 1).toFixed(), i, {template: templateSheet});
}
```

Comment: This might cause problems if some math is needed with the numbers at any point. I’d suggest changing the number format as a general rule.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You can set the number format of a range of cells using the `.setNumberFormat()` method of the Range class.*

#### More Information:

Google Sheets has a set of number formats which can be used for displaying numbers in cells. These define things like the number of decimal points, significant figures, percentages, etc.

In order to remove the trailing '0's you can set the number format of your range to not display numbers after the decimal point.

#### Code Example:

Here I've modified your script with the assumption that the month dates are in column `A`, but you can change the range as you desire:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < text; i++)
{
  ss.insertSheet((i + 1).toFixed(), i, {template: templateSheet}) 
    .getRange("A1:A").setNumberFormat("#");
}
```

Or, if you want to set the number format on the whole Sheet:

```
for (var i = 0; i < text; i++)
{
  var ns = ss.insertSheet((i + 1).toFixed(), i, {template: templateSheet}) 
  ns.getRange(1, 1, ns.getLastRow(), ns.getLastColumn()).setNumberFormat("#");
}
```

#### References:

- [Class Range | Apps Script - `setNumberFormat()` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat)
- [Date and Number Formats | Sheets API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#number_format_patterns)